# How to display hierarchy in breadcrumb

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs, angular-breadcrumb

I am new to using Angular and would like to include a dynamic global breadcrumb. I have Component Hierarchy as component1->component2->component3->component4.
The second component takes id from the first component and third component takes id from second component and so on.

breadcrumb.component.html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let breadcrumb of (breadcrumbs$ | async)">
      <a [href]="breadcrumb.url">{{ breadcrumb.label }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

breadcrumb.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Breadcrumb } from 'src/models/Breadcrumb';
import { BreadcrumbService } from 'src/services/breadcrumb.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumb',
  templateUrl: './breadcrumb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumb.component.css']
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent {

  breadcrumbs$: Observable<Breadcrumb[]>;

  constructor(private readonly breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService) {
    this.breadcrumbs$ = breadcrumbService.breadcrumbs$;
  }

}
```

breadcrumb model

```
export interface Breadcrumb {
    label: string;
    url: string;
}
```

breadcrumb service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Data, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Breadcrumb } from 'src/models/Breadcrumb';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BreadcrumbService {

  // Subject emitting the breadcrumb hierarchy
  private readonly _breadcrumbs$ = new BehaviorSubject<Breadcrumb[]>([]);

  // Observable exposing the breadcrumb hierarchy
  readonly breadcrumbs$ = this._breadcrumbs$.asObservable();

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      // Filter the NavigationEnd events as the breadcrumb is updated only when the route reaches its end
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(event => {
      // Construct the breadcrumb hierarchy
      const root = this.router.routerState.snapshot.root;
      const breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[] = [];
      this.addBreadcrumb(root, [], breadcrumbs);

      // Emit the new hierarchy
      this._breadcrumbs$.next(breadcrumbs);
    });
  }

  private addBreadcrumb(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, parentUrl: string[], breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[]) {
    if (route) {
      // Construct the route URL
      const routeUrl = parentUrl.concat(route.url.map(url => url.path));

      // Add an element for the current route part
      if (route.data.breadcrumb) {
        const breadcrumb = {
          label: this.getLabel(route.data),
          url: '/' + routeUrl.join('/')
        };
        breadcrumbs.push(breadcrumb);
      }

      // Add another element for the next route part
      //this.addBreadcrumb(route.firstChild, routeUrl, breadcrumbs);
    }
  }

  private getLabel(data: Data) {
    // The breadcrumb can be defined as a static string or as a function to construct the breadcrumb element out of the route data
    return typeof data.breadcrumb === 'function' ? data.breadcrumb(data) : data.breadcrumb;
  }

}
```

I am not sure what is the correct way to mention routes. I have tried multiple StackOverflow solutions but it does not work. The ids are there in individual components but I need them on global level to be accessed in breadcrumb.

Answer (score 0):

Your routing structure is completely up to you, but to make your life easier you can have ids as a part of router URLs. e.g. [www.host.com/category/:cId/subcategory/:scId](http://www.host.com/category/:cId/subcategory/:scId).
With such approach, you are able to access ids with the angular router.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {}
...

this.route.paramMap.get('cId');
this.route.paramMap.get('scId');

OR

this.route.params.cId;
this.route.params.scId;
```

In case you're not able to read parameters from the parent routes consider setting paramsInheritanceStrategy to 'always' (https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions).